# node-red list content of a dynamic file name

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am trying to list all the content of a certain directory dynamically (the name of the folder is dynamic); and I'm facing some issues.

I found the `node-red-contrib-fs` node that list all the file in a directory and is pretty useful.

[image: node]

But I have not managed to pass the file name to it other than as a static field below.

[image: node fields]

Passing `{{{global.path}}}` or `{{{global}}}` in the Start Folder field does not work.

Neither do having the path in `msg.filename` or `msg.foldername` works.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the info [sidebar](https://github.com/TotallyInformation/node-red-contrib-fs/blob/master/fs/fs-file-lister.html#L168) for the node, the Start Folder and Pattern can be overridden by passing in a `msg` object with the following fields `msg.payload.start` and `msg.payload.pattern`

Comment: I actually went ahead and just used an `exec` node with a `ls` command, but thanks for the info, I will make sure to try it the next time I need it.